# seleccionar valores máximos

Tags: r, tidyverse

Tengo df del tipo siguiente:

```
col1   col2   col3
A      op1    552
A      op1    325
A      op1    689
B      op1    374
B      op2    148
B      op2    284
B      op3    185
B      op3    857
B      op3    148
```

Necesito para todos los valores de col1, filtrar para todos los de col2 los dos valores más altos de col3, y que quede esto:

```
col1   col2   col3
A      op1    552
A      op1    689
B      op1    374
B      op2    284
B      op3    185
B      op3    857
```

Pero no consigo aclararme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando `tidyverse/dplyr` una forma sencilla sería:

```
df %>% 
  arrange(col1, col2, desc(col3)) %>% 
  group_by(col1, col2) %>% 
  filter(row_number() <= 2)
```

Básicamente, ordenamos, agrupamos y filtramos las dos primeras filas de cada grupo.

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción con [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr)

```
df %>% 
  group_by(col1, col2) %>% 
  slice_max(col3, n=2)
```